# Copying data from two different tables (table1 & table2) to a third newly created table (table3) using explicit cursor

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

I have an assignment problem that i can't manage to fix and got totally stuck on.

I've got two tables (`table1` and `table2` which i created and filled with data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
pnr VARCHAR2(11) PRIMARY KEY,
fnamn VARCHAR2(20),
enamn VARCHAR2(20),
bor_i VARCHAR2(20),
jobbar_i VARCHAR2(20));


CREATE TABLE Table2(
regnr VARCHAR2(6) PRIMARY KEY,
pnr REFERENCES bilägare(pnr),
tillverkare VARCHAR2(20),
modell VARCHAR2(20),
årsmodell NUMBER(4),
hk NUMBER(4),
datum DATE);
```

Now i created a third table (`table3`) which I want to fill with data from `table1` and `table2` using an anonymous `PL-SQL block` and `explicit cursor`. I created the third table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table3(
pnr VARCHAR2(11),
fnamn VARCHAR2(20),
enamn VARCHAR2(20),
regnr VARCHAR2(6),
tillverkare VARCHAR2(20),
modell VARCHAR2(20));
```

How can I fill it (table3) with data from table1 and table2? I also only want to fill it with data from those who have got more than 200 hk (have a look at table1). How do I manage to fix this? Thankful for all the help I can get.

Comment: Given it's just a join on pnr?, why do you want a cursor? Insert into or select into, can't remember which one or both oracle uses will do the job just fine, from what you've posted.  Oh wasn't me who marked you down either. Though you probably deserve it for the apparent lack of effort on your part. This place expects people to demonstrate having a go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help :) I solved it the following way

```
declare
    cursor c_fartdåre
    is
       select pnr,
              bilägare.fnamn,
              bilägare.enamn,
              fordon.regnr,
              fordon.tillverkare,
              fordon.modell
         from bilägare
        inner join fordon
        using (pnr)
        where fordon.hk > 200;
        c_fartdåre_rec c_fartdåre%rowtype;
/*v_pnr         fordon.pnr%type;
v_fnamn       bilägare.fnamn%type;
v_enamn       bilägare.enamn%type;
v_regnr       fordon.regnr%type;
v_tillverkare fordon.tillverkare%type;
v_modell      fordon.modell%type;*/
begin

if not c_fartdåre%isopen then
open c_fartdåre;
end if;

loop
fetch c_fartdåre into c_fartdåre_rec;
exit when c_fartdåre%notfound;

  insert into fartdåre(pnr, fnamn, enamn, regnr, tillverkare, modell)
  values(c_fartdåre_rec.pnr, c_fartdåre_rec.fnamn, c_fartdåre_rec.enamn, c_fartdåre_rec.regnr, c_fartdåre_rec.tillverkare, c_fartdåre_rec.modell);
end loop;


commit;
dbms_output.put_line('Kopieringen är klar!');
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

As an explicit cursor in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE
   -- Explicit cursor
   CURSOR tab3_cur
   IS
      SELECT pnr,
             t1.fnam,
             t1.enam,
             t2.regnr,
             t2.tillverkare,
             t2.modell
        FROM table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
       USING (pnr)
       WHERE t2.hk > 200;

   -- Collection for holding the cursor results
   TYPE tab3_cur_tabtype IS TABLE OF table3%ROWTYPE
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   tab3_tab tab3_cur_tabtype;
BEGIN
   -- Open the cursor and fetch the records
   OPEN tab3_cur;
   FETCH tab3_cur BULK COLLECT INTO tab3_tab;
   CLOSE tab3_cur;

   -- insert all the records into table3
   FORALL x IN INDICES OF tab3_tab
      INSERT INTO table3
      VALUES (tab3(x));

   -- Commit the inserts
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Check the cursor is closed
      IF tab3_cur%ISOPEN
      THEN
         CLOSE tab3_cur;
      END IF;
      -- Rollback any inserted records
      ROLLBACK;
      -- Re-raise the error
      RAISE;
END;
/
```

It would be far better and more efficient to just use:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (
   pnr,
   enam,
   regnr,
   tillverkare,
   modell
)
SELECT pnr,
       t1.fnam,
       t1.enam,
       t2.regnr,
       t2.tillverkare,
       t2.modell
  FROM table1 t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2
 USING (pnr)
 WHERE t2.hk > 200;
```

Hope it helps...